# When is a compost considered safe if it contains restricted animal material?

Tags: composting

If a compost contains [RAM](https://becfeedsolutions.com.au/faq-items/what-is-restricted-animal-material-ram/)(restricted animal material), what are the indicators one should look at in order to determine whether it is safe for pasture use.

Comment: Where I come from RAM means radioactive materials. Definitely not safe for composting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Minnesota Department of Agriculture provides a guide to [composting animal mortalities](https://www.mda.state.mn.us/news/publications/animals/compostguide.pdf) which suggests that a compost pile is safe when the internal temperature is recorded above 130ºF or 55ºC for seven days in a row.

> Once the pile reaches at least 130º F, it should stay above that temperature for at least one week. Do not start counting the days until the area that you added to the pile last reaches this temperature. When the temperature drops, the pile is ready to be turned.

In [British Columbia](http://www.bclaws.ca/Recon/document/ID/freeside/18_2002#division_d2e969), a temperature of 50º C for ten consecutive days is sufficient to produce compost graded as "Class A" safe.

> "... at a temperature of not less than 50° Celsius for at least 10 consecutive days. The process must be configured (batch, plug flow, staged) to maintain sufficient retention time to ensure that pathogen and volatile solids destruction is reliably achieved."